# When does local properties of a topological space imply global ones?

Tags: general-topology

Let's say we have a cover $\{U_i \}_i$ of a topological space $X$ where each open set $U_i$ in the cover has some property, when it is the case that this translates into a property of $X$? Could any general statement be made?

The motivation for this is the following problem a friend gave me,

> Call a topological space $X$ reducible if there exists  closed subsets $Y, Z \subset X$, proper and non empty, such that $Y \cup Z =X$. Otherwise, $X$ is irreducible. We say $X$ is sober if every nonempty irreducible closed subset of $X$ is the closure of a unique point, called the generic point of that subset. that is, for any non empty closed irreducible $Z \subset X$ , there exists a unique point $p$ w/ $Z=\overline{p}$
>
> Show that if $X$ has an open cover by sober spaces then $X$ is sober.

The problem is not really relevant to thing here. It could have been rather "when does local connectedness implies global connectedness" for instance.

Comment: That was not my question. You wrote "property and non empty," and you already corrected it.

Comment: This question seems pretty broad, so I wonder what sort of answer you're hoping for. An effective way to check whether a given property is global-if-local, besides just trying to prove it?

Comment: Yeah around those lines.. thinking survey like

Comment: There is no general solution here. Properties can be defined arbitrarily, and so they can apply to arbitrary collection of spaces. In fact any partitioning of the collection of all spaces into two subcollections is a property. And so you ask "which subcollection of the collection of all spaces is closed under local-to-global"? It's impossible to simplify such statement in general.